# Group array according to the same element they have using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have this kind of array that has `date` and `id` only.

```
temp:[
    0:{
     id:"1"
     date:"2017-11-07"
    }
    1:{
    id:"2"
     date:"2017-11-05"
    }
    2:{
     id:"3"
     date:"2017-11-05"
    }
    3:{
     id:"4"
     date:"2017-11-01"
    }
    4:{
     id:"5"
     date:"2017-11-01"
    }
    ]
```

I just want to group it like this

```
data:[
    0:{
      0:[id:"1",date:"2017-11-07"]
    }
    1:{
      0:[id:"2",date:"2017-11-05"],
      1:[id:"3",date:"2017-11-05"]
    }
    2:{
      0:[id:"4",date:"2017-11-01"],
      1:[id:"5",date:"2017-11-01"]
    }]
```

I have a code from `php`, and it work well in,

this is my code in `php`:

```
$newTemp = array();
foreach($temp as $value){
  $newTemp[$value['id'].'_'.$value['date']][] = $value;  
}
```

but I don't know how I will use it in `javascript`

Can you help me with my code, on how I should group the date of the array

Comment: Don't use blockquote in inappropriate places

Comment: Are you sure your php example works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a hash table for defining the same group and push any new group to the result set.

```js
var data = [{ id: "1", date: "2017-11-07" }, { id: "2", date: "2017-11-05" }, { id: "3", date: "2017-11-05" }, { id: "4", date: "2017-11-01" }, { id: "5", date: "2017-11-01" }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!hash[o.date]) {
        hash[o.date] = [];
        result.push(hash[o.date]);
    }
    hash[o.date].push(o);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You are using javascript's variable referencing here right? when you push to  hash[o.date], you are also updating result[hash[o.date]] array because they are the same references.

Comment: @TahaPaksu, right, both share the same reference to the array, so a single pushing is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I sometimes forget these things while coding in different languages. I wonder how you people keep all these things in your minds :)