# Transform array by combining same element

Tags: javascript, arrays

> I been trying to minimize my code by combining same data in one
>   multidimensional array.

here is my array :

```
data:[
    0:{
        id:"1"
        date:"2017-11-27"
        type:"Meeting"
        log_in:"06:30:00"
        log_out:"11:50:00"
    }
    1:{
        id:"1"
        date:"2017-11-27"
        type:"Lunch"
        log_in:"12:00:00"
        log_out:"01:00:00"
    }
    2:{
        id:"1"
        date:"2017-11-27"
        type:"Seminar"
        log_in:"1:15:00"
        log_out:"03:05:00"
    }
    3:{
        id:"1"
        date:"2017-11-28"
        type:"Lunch"
        log_in:"12:00:00"
        log_out:"01:00:00"
    }
    4:{
        id:"1"
        date:"2017-12-28"
        type:"Out of the Office"
        log_in:"03:00:00"
        log_out:"05:00:00"
    } ]
```

I been trying to transform my array to this:

```
new_data:[
    0:{
     id:"1"
     date:"2017-11-27"
     logs:[
        {type:"Meeting",log_in:"06:30:00",log_out:"11:50:00"},
        {type:"Lunch",log_in:"12:00:00",log_out:"01:00:00"},
        {type:"Seminar",log_in:"1:15:00",log_out:"03:05:00"}
     ]
    }
    1:{
     id:"1"
     date:"2017-11-28"
     logs:[
        {type:"Lunch",log_in:"12:00:00",log_out:"01:00:00"},
        {type:"Out of the Office",log_in:"03:00:00",log_out:"05:00:00"}
     ]
    }
]
```

> I have try the code in this is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152972/group-array-according-to-the-same-element-they-have-using-javascript) but I cannot manipulate it
>   well. I just use the right answer in the that link.

Comment: Post your code so we can help you figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: you can check the link, we have same array, but different output

Comment: If you'd followed the examples in those links, you'd most likely already have a working solution. So obviously you didn't do the same and you need to post _your_ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. Using reduce to iterate through the element of the initial array and adding the event to the logs if the element with id and date already exists or creating a new element otherwise.

```js
const data = [
    {
        id:"1",
        date:"2017-11-27",
        type:"Meeting",
        log_in:"06:30:00",
        log_out:"11:50:00"
    },
    {
        id:"1",
        date:"2017-11-27",
        type:"Lunch",
        log_in:"12:00:00",
        log_out:"01:00:00"
    },
    {
        id:"1",
        date:"2017-11-27",
        type:"Seminar",
        log_in:"1:15:00",
        log_out:"03:05:00"
    },
    {
        id:"1",
        date:"2017-11-28",
        type:"Lunch",
        log_in:"12:00:00",
        log_out:"01:00:00"
    },
    {
        id:"1",
        date:"2017-12-28",
        type:"Out of the Office",
        log_in:"03:00:00",
        log_out:"05:00:00"
    } ];



const result = data.reduce((acc, elt) => {
  const {id, date, type: typeValue, log_in, log_out} = elt;
  // Check if the element exists
  const existingEltIndex = acc.findIndex(e =>
    e.id === elt.id && e.date === elt.date);
  const newEvent = {type: typeValue, log_in, log_out};
  
  if (existingEltIndex < 0) { // new element
    const newElement = {
      id,
      date,
      logs: [newEvent]
    };
    return [...acc, newElement];
  } else { // Existing element
    acc[existingEltIndex].logs.push(newEvent);
    return acc;
  }
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your data you want the logs grouped by dates. With this in mind you first create a new array via `map`. Then in each iteration you grab all the objects with dates equal to your current object via `filter()`. Lastly you create one more array for your current objects `log` attribute, comprised of objects described in your question.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    date: "2017-11-27",
    type: "Meeting",
    log_in: "06:30:00",
    log_out: "11:50:00"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    date: "2017-11-27",
    type: "Lunch",
    log_in: "12:00:00",
    log_out: "01:00:00"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    date: "2017-11-27",
    type: "Seminar",
    log_in: "1:15:00",
    log_out: "03:05:00",
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    date: "2017-11-28",
    type: "Lunch",
    log_in: "12:00:00",
    log_out: "01:00:00"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    date: "2017-12-28",
    type: "Out of the Office",
    log_in: "03:00:00",
    log_out: "05:00:00"
  }
];

const newData = data.map(obj => {
  const { id, date } = obj;
  
  const currObj = { id, date };

  currObj['logs'] = data.filter(dataObj => {
    return date === dataObj['date'];
  }).map(obj => {
    const {type, log_in, log_out } = obj;
    
    return { type, log_in, log_out };
  });
  
  return currObj;
});

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration),

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    date: "2017-11-27",
    type: "Meeting",
    log_in: "06:30:00",
    log_out: "11:50:00"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    date: "2017-11-27",
    type: "Lunch",
    log_in: "12:00:00",
    log_out: "01:00:00"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    date: "2017-11-27",
    type: "Seminar",
    log_in: "1:15:00",
    log_out: "03:05:00",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    date: "2017-11-28",
    type: "Lunch",
    log_in: "12:00:00",
    log_out: "01:00:00"
   },
   {
      id: "2",
      date: "2017-12-28",
      type: "Out of the Office",
      log_in: "03:00:00",
      log_out: "05:00:00"
   }
];

var newObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

    //if a obj for this id does not exist yet, create
    if (newObj[data[i].id] == undefined)
    {
       newObj[data[i].id] = {"id": data[i].id, "date": data[i].date, "logs": []};
    }

    //store log into logs array using obj id
    newObj[data[i].id].logs.push({"type" : data[i].type, "log_in" : data[i].log_in, "log_out" : data[i].log_out});
}

console.log(newObj);
```